# Messed up meshes when moving things

Tags: modeling, animation

When I move my objects in the scene they smear out and destroys totally. How to I set this up properly (seems like VERY basic stuff)? Destroyed in the picture is a horse, jockey and wagon..
[image]

Comment: it's hard to guess, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It seems like these meshes have armature(s) and you try to move the meshes without the armatures. Check it in the outliner or hit alt+h to reveal the hidden objects.